# C# calling Delphi DLL that returns structure within structure

Tags: c#, delphi, pinvoke

Yet another Delphi interop question......

I have this Delphi code:

```
library DelphiDll;

uses
  Dialogs,
  SysUtils,
  Classes;

  type
    TestEnum = (teOne, teTwo);

    TTestRecord = record
    end;

    TTestType = record
      MyTestRecords: array [1..255] of TTestRecord;
      MyTestEnum: TestEnum;
    end;

  {$R *.res}

  function DllFunction(var testType: TTestType): Boolean stdcall; export;

  begin
    testType.MyTestEnum := teTwo;

    Result := True;
  end;

  exports DllFunction;

  begin
  end.
```

And this C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DelpiDllTester
{
    public enum TestEnum
    {
        One,
        Two
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct TestType
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 255)]
        public TestRecord[] MyTestRecords;
        public TestEnum MyTestEnum;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct TestRecord
    {
    }

    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("DelphiDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern bool DllFunction(ref TestType testType);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestType testType = new TestType();
            bool dllFunctionResult = DllFunction(ref testType);

            Console.WriteLine(dllFunctionResult);
            Console.WriteLine(testType.MyTestEnum);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the C# code, the console output for testType.MyTestEnum is always the enum value One even though it is clearly set to Two in the Delphi code.

Now, if I simply change from using the array of TestRecord structures in the TestType structure to using a simple array of integers, all is well.

Why does the array of integers work yet the array of structures does not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is the fact that `TTestRecord` has no contents defined in it. The C# code marshals that as a field of size 1. The Delphi compiler regards that as having size 0. And hence there is a mismatch between the two structures. The C# code returns 260 for `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TestType))` whereas the Delphi compiler returns 8 for `SizeOf(TTestType)`.

In the real code presumably there will be some actual content in that record and when you do that, everything will start to work.

Note that @JMarsch and @Ken White make valid points too. You will need to make sure that the enum is being marshalled correctly and that the `struct` layouts match. Because of the way structs are padded, you may get away without doing anything to your enum marshalling, but you may equally well be unlucky!

Comment: Doh!  You ever have one of those days where you just get stuck in a rut of thinking and can't seem to break out.  The code I presented was a trimmed down example of the real code, but I wasn't paying attention to the fact that my trimmed down code, with the empty record, would cause such a problem.  Thanks again for all of the comments.  Next time I will pay closer attention.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a whole other lifetime since I used Delphi (like '98), but, as I remember, enums in Delphi were 1 byte numbers.  Enums in c# are ints (32-bit).

So, you might try defining your c# enum as an

```
enum TestEnum: byte {One, Two}
```

The thing this does not explain is how it worked with an array of int.  About the only other thing I can think of is to make sure that the values of the c# enum exactly match those of the Delphi Enum (so use teOne, teTwo), but since we are really talking about an integer/byte under the covers, I don't see how that would matter.

Comment: I was also thinking that there must be a issue with how enum types are handled in c# as opposed to Delphi.  It actually ended up being a much simpler problem that I was ignoring.  The empty record was the culprit all along.  Thanks for the help, though.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the enumeration size in your Delphi code. Delphi will make it as small as possible, but the .NET side expects an `int`. Add the following to your code before the enumeration declaration:

```
{$MINENUMSIZE 4}   // can also use {$Z4} but it's not clear later when
                   // you're trying to maintain the code.
                   // Or you can use {$Z-} and {$Z+}, for
                   // {$Z1} and {$Z4} respectively

// Your enum declaration

{$MINENUMSIZE 1}
```

Comment: See my answer. Whilst this issue is relevant, there is a much bigger elephant in the room.

Comment: I was working under the assumption that the poster knew a record with no content wasn't going to work, and that this was mocked-up code for explanatory purposes. Indeed, if it isn't and the poster is trying to use a no-content record in real code, that would be a bigger elephant. (Actually, re-reading the text below the post, I think you've got it - I think it probably **is** real code, as indicated by "change...to using a simple array of integers". Nice catch, and +1 to your answer.)

Comment: I actually did know this, but I had such tunnel vision about the enum that I couldn't see what was sitting right in front of my face.  I was thinking along the same lines as you, however, that didn't solve my problem because of the empty record issue.  I just couldn't get out of my one train of thought.  Thanks for the help, though.